# Conditional with date and groups

Tags: r, date

I have this dataset:

```
class = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")
date = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2014/12/01"), by = "month")                    
value = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0, 0, 0)
data =data.frame(cbind(date, class, value))
```

And I need to  to know if in the next three months there is a one by  class. For example: the "b" class starts in  2014/02/01 so I need to check if inside the range of 2014/02/01 and 2014/04/01 there is a zero (variable value) in that class, creating a new variable that take the value of one if the last condition is fulfilled.

I tried to use dplyr with group_by and mutate but I couldn't solve.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output variable?

Comment: That `cbind` operation is going to screw up everything. It's going to coerce everything to 'character'. Just leave it out and you will be happier.